# My backend site is serving broken images in the browser

Tags: express, src

I recently started a backend using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB.

When I put pictures they don't show up in the browser.

What could be the problem? They show up as broken images.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: right click on the image and figure out what location it is attempting to access the image